# Make number picker with ellipse enabled at its end

Tags: android

I'm having the below issue:

[image]

The text does not fit. Can i enable `ellipse="end"` somehow or have it adjust its size to accommodate the entire text?

I am using a `NumberPicker` with custom Strings

Answer (score 2):

I also have been trying to get this to work,  I could not get it to ellipsize automatically (or MARQUEE fwiw).  I will share what I did as a workaround, but might not be exactly what you are looking for (it isn't exactly what I want either).  I basically create my own ellipsize at a fixed number (I used 25, it works for small screens that I have tested).  `sa_displayedNames` is what populates the numberpicker.

```
 String[] sa_displayedNames =addEllipsize(sa_displayedNames);

public String[] addEllipsize(String[] sa){
    for(int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++){
        sa[i] =ellipsize(sa[i], 25);
    }
    return sa;
}

public String ellipsize(String input, int maxLength) {
    String s_ellipse = "...";
    if (input ==null || input.length() <= maxLength || input.length() < s_ellipse.length()) return input;
    return input.substring(0, maxLength - s_ellipse.length()).concat(s_ellipse);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got what I need by upgrading seekingStillness's answer.

```
NumberPicker numberPicker;
String[] strings;
EditText editText = numberPicker.findViewById(
            Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("numberpicker_input", "id", "android"));

numberPicker.setDisplayedValues(ellipsizeStringArray(
            strings,
            editText.getPaint(),
            numberPicker.getWidth()));

@NonNull
private String[] ellipsizeStringArray(@NonNull String[] displayedValues,
                                      @NonNull TextPaint textPaint,
                                      int viewWidth) {
    if (viewWidth == 0) {
        return displayedValues;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < displayedValues.length; i++) {

        int textLength = displayedValues[i].length();

        if (displayedValues[i] == null || textLength == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        int textWidth = Math.round(textPaint.measureText(displayedValues[i]));

        if (textWidth <= viewWidth) {
            continue;
        }

        int charLength = textWidth / textLength;
        int maxLength = viewWidth / charLength;

        displayedValues[i] = ellipsize(displayedValues[i], maxLength);
    }

    return displayedValues;
}

@NonNull
private String ellipsize(@NonNull String input, int maxLength) {
    String ellipse = "...";
    if (input.length() <= maxLength
            || input.length() < ellipse.length()
            || maxLength <= ellipse.length) {
        return input;
    }
    return input.substring(0, maxLength - ellipse.length()).concat(ellipse);
}
```